# How can I unit test, that one viewmodel sends to another viewmodel proper string?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mvvm, xamarin.forms, moq

In a view model's constructor I have a command declaration that calls a method:

```
OpenGroupCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnOpenGroupExecute);
```

And the method looks like:

```
private void OnOpenGroupExecute(object obj)
        {
            string groupName = (string)obj;
            Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new GroupPage(groupName));
        }
```

How can I test, that `groupName` is passed to another view model correctly? In another view model `groupName` parameter is sent to `GroupName` property on VM instance:

```
public class GroupPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, IGroupPageViewModel
    {
        private string _groupName;
        public GroupPageViewModel(string groupName)
        {
            LoadGroupName(groupName);
        }
        public void LoadGroupName(string groupName)
        {
            GroupName = groupName;
        }
        public string GroupName
        {
            get
            {
                return _groupName;
            }
            set
            {
                _groupName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

On debug all works fine, but how can I unit test it? Where can I read a bit about testing and mocking stuff like this, even with `Moq` framework?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is actually about how to test navigation between pages.

In the implementation of method OnOpenGroupExecute, because you are using Xamarin forms stuff to implement the navigation, you have to refer Xamarin Forms assemblies in your test project which makes the unit test depend on Xamarin Forms.

As suggested in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/ , try to create an interface for navigation and navigate with viewmodel (more details on https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers)

And in your unit test project, implement a fake navigation service class like below and inject into the DI container:

```
public class FakeNavigationService : INavigationService //this interface is from MS eShopOnContainer project
{
    private List<ViewModelBase> _viewModels = new List<ViewModel>();

    public Task NavigateToAsync<TViewModel>() where TViewModel : ViewModelBase {
        //create viewModel object from DI container
        //var viewModel = ......
        _viewModels.Add(viewModel);
    }

    public ViewModelBase CurrentPageViewModel {
        get {
            if (_viewModels.Count() < 1) {
                return null;
            }
            return _viewModels[_viewModels.Count() - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

This is just a suggestion. If you have implemented most of features in your app, it takes time to change navigate-with-page to navigate-with-viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's see what you have:

1. you have some code in a private method, unless you make that public you won't be able to test it directly, because you can't call it. I am not considering here any tricks that allow you to call private methods.
2. what does that method do? It is not clear at all, it receives an object, we don't know what's in it. You're converting it to string, but what if it is not a string? Can you convert that object to a string? who knows.

So we have a method, that we don't know what it does, we don't know what it receives as parameters, we can't call it directly, but we want to test it.  This is not a good position to be in.

Step back a bit and ask yourself, what are you really trying to test?

You said : *How can I test, that groupName is passed to another view model correctly?*

what does "correctly" mean? You need to define what it means for that string to be *correct*. This will give a test scenario you can work with.

*I expect to receive an object, which looks like A and I want to convert it to a string  which looks like B.* Forget about viewmodels for now, that's just unimportant noise.

You can change the method into a public one and you can test that for different types of input data, you're getting the right result. This is literally, working with an object and extract some stuff from it. When that method is correct, you can guarantee that the viewmodel will receive the right input and that is good enough from a unit testing point of view.

You can of course add more tests for various inputs, you can test for correct failure conditions etc.